# apply, sapply and lappy return NULL

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I have a matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,-1,-1,-1,-1), ncol = 4 , nrow = 4)
```

and I apply the following functions to filter out the columns with only positive entries, but for the columns that have negative entries I get a `NULL`. How can I suppress the `NULL`s from the output of `lapply`, `apply` and `sapply`?

```
> lapply(as.data.frame(mat), function(x) { if( all(x >= 0) ){return(x)} })
$V1
[1] 0 0 0 0

$V2
[1] 1 1 1 1

$V3
NULL

$V4
[1] 0 0 0 0

> sapply(as.data.frame(mat), function(x) { if( all(x >= 0) ){return(x)} })
$V1
[1] 0 0 0 0

$V2
[1] 1 1 1 1

$V3
NULL

$V4
[1] 0 0 0 0


> apply(mat, 2, function(x){if (all(x >= 0)){return(x)}})
[[1]]
[1] 0 0 0 0

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 1 1

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
[1] 0 0 0 0
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about

```
dd <- as.data.frame(mat)
dd[sapply(dd,function(x) all(x>=0))]
```

?

- `sapply(...)` returns a logical vector (in this case `TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE`) that states whether the columns have all non-negative values.
- when used with a *data frame* (not a matrix), single-bracket indexing with a logical vector treats the data frame as a list (which it is) and creates a list containing just the specified elements.

Or alternatively

```
dd[apply(mat>=0,2,all)]
```

In this case we use `apply(...,2,...)` on the original matrix to generate the logical indexing vector.

or

```
mat[,apply(mat>=0,2,all)]
```

In this case since we are indexing a matrix we use `[,logical_vector]` to select columns.

Comment: thanks, but how come that works even when you don't put a comma before the sapply?

Comment: `mat[,colSums(mat>=0)>0]` also

Answer (score 8):

Another option is to `Filter` your result while `Negate`ing `NULL`s (if you want to keep it in a list format)

```
Res <- lapply(as.data.frame(mat), function(x) if(all(x >= 0)) x)
Filter(Negate(is.null), Res)
# $V1
# [1] 0 0 0 0
# 
# $V2
# [1] 1 1 1 1
# 
# $V4
# [1] 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: or just do it in `Filter` to begin with: `Filter(function(x) all(x >= 0), as.data.frame(mat))` to avoid an extra loop (can use `as.list` at the end if necessary)

Comment: @eddi nice one, didn't think  of it.